# problemas durante autocargado

Tags: php

Me encuentro haciendo una API utilizando PHP como lenguaje de programación para codificarla

### Mi problema:

En mi autoloader, incluyo cada archivo con extensión .php en el mismo directorio que significa una clase cada uno (con un `foreach()`, usando `require()`), pero cuando incluye clases por ejemplo `CreateUrl` que usan traits retorna el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Trait 'Endpoint' not found in
>   /home/web/site.com/api/v2/classes/CreateUrl.php on line 11

y se detiene el autoloading. Lo que no entiendo es, no he initialized como se dice la clase y todavía el autoloader no termina de cargar las clases, por eso, no entiendo.

Gracias

### Lo que he intentado

Este ha sido el intento (de usar traits) para poder extender/usar métodos y propiedades de más de una clase.

Archivo classes-load.php:

```
<?php
const AUTOLOAD_DIRECTORY = '/home/web/site.com/classes/';

foreach(glob(AUTOLOAD_DIRECTORY.'*.php') as $class){
  if(preg_match('/autoload.php/', $class)){
    continue;
  }
  require $class;
}

foreach(glob(AUTOLOAD_DIRECTORY.'*.php') as $class){
  if(preg_match('/autoload.php/', $class)){
    continue;
  }
  $class = str_replace('.php', '', $class);
  new $class;
}
```

Saludos

Comment: Alguna respuesta? Como es posible.
Tengo mis clientes sin servicio API desde ayer.